# Getting Python import error although the path is correct

Tags: python

**detector_main.py**

```
import ast
import os
import fpdf

from Detector.class_coupling_detector import detect_class_cohesion
from Detector.cyclomatic_complexity_detector import detect_cyclomatic_complexity
from Detector.long_lambda_detector import detect_long_lambda
from Detector.long_list_comp_detector import detect_long_list_comp
from Detector.pylint_output_detector import detect_pylint_output
from Detector.shotgun_surgery_detector import detect_shotgun_surgery
from Detector.useless_exception_detector import detect_useless_exception
from tools.viz_generator import add_viz

import sys

def main(directory):
    # Get stats for files in directory
    stats_dict = get_stats(directory)
    ...
```

I have a bunch of imports in this file. When I run this file, (the parameter is a string path to the directory), I get the following error

```
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/src/detector_main.py", line 12
    from ../tools.viz_generator import add_viz
```

and my project structure looks like below:

[image]

[image]

I feel like these inputs are not consistent and could be more organized. I just wrote a bunch of scripts and important that way but I feel like there is a way to make this into a more consistent package where users can run it anywhere with import issues.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a Python Package.

https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/

> Working with Python packages is really simple. All you need to do is:
>
> Create a directory and give it your package's name. Put your classes
>   in it. Create a **init**.py file in the directory That's all! In order
>   to create a Python package, it is very easy. The **init**.py file is
>   necessary because with this file, Python will know that this directory
>   is a Python package directory other than an ordinary directory (or
>   folder – whatever you want to call it). Anyway, it is in this file
>   where we'll write some import statements to import classes from our
>   brand new package.

What I do is put my packages in

> PYTHON_PATH\Lib\site-packages\MYPACKAGE

then in the `__init__.py`

```
from .function_scripts import *
```

Comment: what is I don't have classes and I just import a bunch of scripts? (only has `def`s)

Comment: Doesn't matter. A package is just a bunch of modules, which are actually any .py files.

Comment: When you say `Create a directory and give it your package's name. Put your classes in it` does that mean just put all other scripts in that folder? Or will directories be also fine?

Comment: Updated with more instruction